# python flask socketio not working - import failiture

Tags: python, flask-socketio, python-socketio

I'm trying to use socketio inside my flaks app, but for some reason, it is not working. When I try to run my app with this module, I get the following error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'socketio.exceptions'

I tried to pip install flask and flask-socketio both from existing and new virtual environments, but it does not work...

Any ideas what is wrong? Python version 3.7

My code is following:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.event
def my_event(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': 'got it!'})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall flask-socketio
`pip uninstall flask-socketio && pip install flask-socketio`
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/1105#issuecomment-564005613

Comment: I tried, but, unfortunately, did not work.

Comment: which os is you using? ubuntu?
try to uninstall any other installations. Check `apt list --installed | grep socketio` and reinstall using pip